# Datatable - Change to the clicked page after the callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable which needs to be paginated. I have used the `page-dt` event to fire a function to load data from the server side when clicked on a page number. Then I used `$('#table').dataTable().fnAddData(recordsArray);` to append newly retrieved data to the table. This happens successfully. My problem is, even though data is being appended to the table, it keeps on the first page despite the click event. I tried with `table.rows.add(recordsArray).draw();` and `fnDrawCallback` event, but still had no success.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
           table = $('#table').DataTable({
                "filter": true,
                "paging":true,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "pageLength": 5,
                 scrollCollapse: true,
                 scrollY:'70vh',
                "dom": '<"dataTablesTop"' +
                'f' +
                '<"dataTables_toolbar">' +
                '>' +
                'rt' +
                '<"dataTablesBottom"' +
                'lip' +
                '>',
                "info":true
            });
        $('#table').on('page.dt', function (e, settings) {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(settings));
            update(settings);
        });
        });
```

This is the `update()` method.

```
    update = function(data) {
        alert(data);
        var displayStart = data._iDisplayStart;
        var displayLength = data._iDisplayLength;
        var records = data.aiDisplay.length;
        if(displayStart != 0) {
            var data = getProviderData(displayStart, displayLength, records, true);
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
                no = no + 1;
                data[i].no = no;
                try {
                    var json =  data[i].jsonBody.replace(/\\n/g, "")
                        .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
                        .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
                        .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
                        .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
                        .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
                        .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
                        .replace("%", "")
                        .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");

                    data[i].jsonContent = JsonHuman.format(JSON.parse(json)).outerHTML;
                }
                catch (e) {
                    data[i].jsonContent = data[i].jsonBody;
                }
            }

            var recordsArray = [];
            for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                var temp = [];
                temp.push(data[j].no);
                temp.push(data[j].responseTime);
                temp.push(data[j].api);
                temp.push(data[j].jsonContent);
                recordsArray.push(temp);
            }
            // table.rows.add(recordsArray).draw();
            $('#table').dataTable().fnAddData(recordsArray);
        }
        // drawGadget();
        // wso2gadgets.update(data,"append");
return;
    };
```

[image: Please see the screenshot]

Appreciate any inputs on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from what i remember datables had a option where you can automatically ajax the data on datatable newpage

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: This is not actually for the new page. Suppose I have initially loaded 2-3 pages. Then when I click on the second page, I need the data for the 4th page to be loaded and moved to the second page.

Comment: why do you need to do that?

Comment: The server side and datatable logic was pretty complex actually. It's created by a gadget server. So if I got to change that part, I had to change a huge code. Anyway, I got this done by simply adding false parameter to table.rows.add(recordsArray).draw(); method. 
Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that simply done by making `table.rows.add(recordsArray).draw();` to `table.rows.add(recordsArray).draw(false);`.

Comment: Nice! here's the link to the [function's docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) in case anyone wants to know more.